# adding n number of variable to function in r

Tags: r

I want to make my function to take any number of data as supplied by the user and then the code work on the no. of data provided by the user. Can I do this in R?

Below is the sample of what i want to do:

```
myfunction<-function(data1,data2,data3,datan) #n no. of data parts 
{
   data1<-(data1)*2
   data2<-(data2)*2
   data3<-(data3)*2
   datan<-(datan)*2
}
```

so suppose a user enters only one data which is  data1 then the operation take place  only on  data1 and there is no requirement for other data parts and the user gets the output

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `...`

```
myfun <- function(...) {
  dat.lst <- list(...)
  dat.lst.new <- lapply(dat.lst, function(x){return(x*2)})
  return(dat.lst.new)
}

myfun(c(1, 2), matrix(1:9, 3,3))
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 4

# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    8   14
# [2,]    4   10   16
# [3,]    6   12   18
```

Comment: To the OP: it should be stressed that `R` passes arguments by value and so the arguments aren't actually changed once the function exits. That's why the above function returns a `list` with all the arguments changed, since the original objects will stay unchanged.

Comment: @nicola agree with you . its is changing the argument class type which is surely i don't want to change

Comment: @VenYao any other way around of doing this without using lapply and loop .